# Controller spec + draper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2, draper

I'm using rspec and draper gem https://github.com/jcasimir/draper

In my controller it's a simple action show

```
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @products = ProductDecorator.decorate(@category.products)
end
```

and test

```
describe "#show" do
  before { @category = Factory :category }
  before do
    @product1 = Factory :product, category: @category
    @product2 = Factory :product, category: @category
  end
  before { get :show, id: @category.id  }

  it { should respond_with :success }
  it { assigns(:products).should eq [@product1, @product2] }
end
```

In project all works fine and products are displayed normally, but in test I get such error

```
Failure/Error: it { assigns(:products).should eq [@product1, @product2] }

   expected: [#<Product ... >, #<Product ...>]
        got: nil

   (compared using ==)
```

also if I replace ProductDecorator.decorate(@category.products) with just @category.products  - no errors

if I inspect @products

```
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @products = ProductDecorator.decorate(@category.products)
  puts @products.inspect
end
```

got

```
#<DecoratedEnumerableProxy of ProductDecorator for [#<Product ...>, #<Product ...>]>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Why just test you have this Decorator define in your assigns ?

```
it { assigns(:products).should eq(ProductDecorator.decorate([@product1, @product2] }))
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this, but what is a difference to compare products array or 'DecoratedEnumerableProxy of ProductDecorator' with nil?